# How to store method pointers to arbitrary class types in the same list?

Tags: c++, c++11, store, pointer-to-member

I need a way to store a list of method pointers, and the method pointers could belong to classes of different types. So for example:

```
vector<MethodPointers> list;

class A {
    void function(int, int) { ... }
}

class B {
    void function(int, int) { ... }
}

A a;
B b;
MethodPointer p1(&A::function, &a);
MethodPointer p2(&B::function, &b);

list.push_back(p1);
list.push_back(p2);
```

What are the c++11 ways to implement this? I have looked at std::bind and got it to work, but it seems like 4 times slower than using a virtual-methods approach, according to my tests. I tried std::mem_fn but could not get it to work. Does anybody know if it can?

The reason I need this is because I have a class which can emit events - and I want arbitrary instances to subscribe to these events as method calls. Is this possible to do?

PS. Conditions apply:
1. I don't want to use Boost
2. I don't want to use a 'Listener' interface, where a subscriber have to subclass an abstract interface class.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: note: 2 - if subclassing is an issue to you, you can also use templates and compile time polymorphism.

Comment: Are you at a point when 4 times slower than a virtual method is of any concern? I mean, virtual dispatch is extremely fast, so four times slower than that is still very, very fast. When you profiled the code, did dispatch take more than five percent of the time?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I don't know yet for sure if it's a big concern. I'm experimenting with different styles. But in the end, it's for a real-time application where there might be significant number of dispatches per frame. My test updates x dataset and each update fires an event. I have measured the time taken between the two styles. With -O3 optimization is just half as slow though.

Comment: Google "fastest possible delegates".  Uses UB, but works and is fast.

Answer (score 2):

Shift the problem: your events are clearly called through the same signature. Store a `std::function<void(Args...)>` and store suitably bound objects in these. If necessary you can expose an interface taking an object reference and a member pointer which does the binding. Chances are suitable function objects can be created which are more efficient, e.g., using a lambda function.

If use of `std::bind()` is slow make sure that all expensive to copy arguments are passed by reference.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What you suggest is what I'm sort of doing atm. I'll remember the reference thing, though I used the same parameters types when i compared vtable and the std::bind approach. I also tried exposing an interface like you said, but you'll run into problems with std::bind since you need to supply it with std::placeholders::_1 for arguments you don't want to bind.